# $X(n)=2^{n}(1-Y(n))$ is a martingale?

Tags: martingales, uniform-distribution

Let $Y(0)$ a random variable uniformly distribuited on $[0,1]$ and define $X(n)=2^{n}(1-Y(n))$  where $Y(n)$ is uniformly distribuited on $[Y_{n-1},1]$. Show that $X(n)$ is a martingale.

I am not sure that $X(n)$ is a Markov process, so I tried to compute the first conditional expectation so

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
      aE(X(1)\,|\,\mathcal{F}_0)&=2E((1-Y(1))\,|\,Y(0))\\
&=2E(u\,|\,Y(0))
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $u$ is uniformly distribuited in $[0,Y_0]$. Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
      2E(u\,|\,Y(0)=y)&=\int_0^y \frac{u}{y}du\\
&=\frac{y}{2}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

my question are: $E(u\,|\,Y(0))=E(u\,|\,Y(0)=y)1_{\{Y(0)=y\}}$? and is $X$  a Markov process?

Comment: You have some problem understanding conditional expectation, where $Y(0)$ is 
abbreviation for $\sigma(Y(0))$. To be short, you can regard the expectation a function of $Y(0)$, and there is no need for another $y$.

Comment: If $Y(1)$ is uniformly distributed on $[Y(0), 1]$, then $1-Y(1)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1-Y(0)]$, not $[0,Y(0)]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how $Y_{n+1}|X_0,X_1,\ldots ,X_n \sim \mathcal{U}\Big[1-2^{-n}X_n,1\Big]$ and so $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{E}\left(X_{n+1}|X_0,X_1,\dots,X_n\right) &=& \mathbb{E}\left(2^{n+1}(1-Y_{n+1})|X_0,X_1,\dots,X_n\right) \\ &=& 2^{n+1}\left(1-\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{n+1}|X_0,X_1,\dots,X_n\right)\right) \\ &=& 2^{n+1}\Big(1-\frac{1-2^{-n}X_n+1}{2}\Big) \\ &=&X_n\end{eqnarray*} $$ Hence $\{X_i\}_{i\geq 0}$ is a martingale. No integration necessary.

Comment: @DonP After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).